# What are the security levels of SFTP?

Tags: ssh, sftp, ssh-keys, private-key, public-key

From what I understand you have different levels of security with SFTP. What are the levels from weakest to strongest?

FTP  - Not possible over SFTP
SFTP - no host key checking
SFTP - host key checking
SFTP - login and password (LAP)
SFTP - LAP + host key

I ask because I've seen this Java code:

```
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
```

And I've read that you can connect to SFTP with and without keys.

FYI My understanding may be way off.

Answer (score 2):

The host key checking indeed contributes to the security of the SSH/SFTP. Though it is in no way related to the authentication (password). So it's not like there are "levels of security" that combine these two aspects.

Moreover, your probably confuse the host key checking with the public key authentication.

Read my [article on SSH keys](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ssh_keys) to understand the difference between the host key and the key used for authentication.

---

Host key checking: You should never set the `StrictHostKeyChecking` to `no`, unless you connect within a private network, where you do not expect any kind of [man-in-the-middle attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack).

Authentication: If possible, use the public key authentications. The password authentication is less secure.

---

The FTP is in no way related to the SFTP. Anyway, I do not know, what you mean by "FTP security level".